# Development of new theme and rollout on multisite

Tags: multisite, child-theme

I'm currently using Wordpress MU with 100+ websites. 
I have 5 active custom theme and one of my theme is being totally redesign. Most functions are preserved in the new version and there is a few addition to it as well.

The theme was design with the same name as the previous version since we were mostly upgrading to a newer look (mostly cosmetic and integration with the Materialize CSS framework). We kept the same structure and all.

I've uploaded the new version on our servers and called the folder XXX_dev so I could roll it slowly on our websites. I didn't want to affect the 80+ websites using the old theme since some had custom CSS in widgets. I was hoping to gently move from on theme to another and retaining most design info since they use the same function/widgets/sidebars etc.

First thing I realize : the theme seems to be loading the old CSS file. I believe so because wether it's a new website with the new theme or an old one with the new theme I see the old version number in the administration.

Second : if I apply the new theme over the old one it will import some of the old customization but I can't make any changes.

While i'm not looking to fix the customization issue I want to know what have I done wrong with the implementation of a new theme while coexisting with an old one. I feel like I should insist here : they are extremely similar with mostly cosmetic changes and a few additions.

Should I change the name of the new theme to something completely different? Should I instead change the name of the OLD theme? Is changing the name of the folder enough or should I also make changes within the theme (like changing the @package to XXX_dev).